# How do I add content in this situation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

So I was trying to build a landing page for a business, and I am not able to add the contents because the div starts from too far down.

But the weird part is that it works when the sidebar is activated. I'm just a beginnner.

```js
const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
const hamburgerButton = document.getElementById('hamburger-button');
const hamburgerIcon = document.getElementById('hamburgerIcon');

hamburgerButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar-visible');
  if (sidebar.classList[1] === 'sidebar-visible') {
    hamburgerIcon.src = 'icons/close-icon.png';
    hamburgerIcon.classList.toggle('close-icon');
  } else if (!sidebar.classList[1]) {
    hamburgerIcon.src = 'icons/hamburger-icon.svg';
    hamburgerIcon.classList.toggle('close-icon');
  }
  // console.log(sidebar.classList[1]);
})
```

```html
<div class="div-hamburger">
  <button class="hamburger-button" id="hamburger-button">
      <img id="hamburgerIcon" class="hamburger-icon" src="icons/hamburger-icon.svg">
    </button>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <div class="div-nav-buttons">
    <button class="home-button nav-buttons">Home</button>
    <button class="contact-button nav-buttons">Contact</button>
    <button class="products-button nav-buttons">Products</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-hidden" id="sidebar">
  <div class="div-menu">
    <button class="sidebar-options">Home</button>
    <button class="sidebar-options">Products</button>
    <button class="sidebar-options">My Orders</button>
    <button class="sidebar-options">My Account</button>
    <button class="sidebar-options">Contact</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div-of-divs">
  <div class="advertisements">
    ad
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="advertisements">
    ad
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change the heights, but it's not working. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You also need to add the (relevant) CSS, and then - ideally - edit the posted code to ensure that the running snippet in your question (that I've just added, from your own posted code) accurately reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**The original post was edited! This is the answer to the original post:**

Given that you have icons in the right directories, you probably want to toggle some content.

In that case there were two issues:

1. Missing parenthesis: `);`. So change the last `}` to `});`.
2. `<script/>` should be below your code inside the `<body/>`.

So the working solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/header.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/sidebar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/body.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Karthikas Traders - Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="div-hamburger">
      <button id="hamburger-button" type="button">
        <img
          id="hamburgerIcon"
          class="hamburger-icon"
          src="icons/hamburger-icon.svg"
        />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="div-nav-buttons">
        <button class="home-button nav-buttons">Home</button>
        <button class="contact-button nav-buttons">Contact</button>
        <button class="products-button nav-buttons">Products</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-hidden" id="sidebar">
      <div class="div-menu">
        <button class="sidebar-options">Home</button>
        <button class="sidebar-options">Products</button>
        <button class="sidebar-options">My Orders</button>
        <button class="sidebar-options">My Account</button>
        <button class="sidebar-options">Contact</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-of-divs">
      <div class="advertisements">ad</div>
      <div class="content">content</div>
      <div class="advertisements">ad</div>
    </div>
    <script>
      const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
      const hamburgerButton = document.getElementById('hamburger-button');
      const hamburgerIcon = document.getElementById('hamburgerIcon');

      hamburgerButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        sidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar-visible');
        if (sidebar.classList[1] === 'sidebar-visible') {
          hamburgerIcon.src = 'icons/close-icon.png';
          hamburgerIcon.classList.toggle('close-icon');
        } else if (!sidebar.classList[1]) {
          hamburgerIcon.src = 'icons/hamburger-icon.svg';
          hamburgerIcon.classList.toggle('close-icon');
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Have a nice day!